# Java: Extend SimpleDateFormat with new pattern letters

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, hebrew

Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is used to format a Date object to a string. The formatter supports various *pattern letters*, which denote textual representation of a Date field. For example, `yy` is two-letter year, `yyyy` is four-letter year, and `E` is day of week.

For example, A `SimpleDateFormat` initialized with `yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z` will format a date to something like `2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT`.

I would like to add some pattern letters to SimpleDateFormat. For example, want `C` to denote Hebrew weekday (`יום ראשון`, `יום שני`, ...).

What's the right way to extend SimpleDateFormat with these new pattern letters? The only online example I could find [seems somewhat complicated](http://home-1.worldonline.nl/~bmc88/java/sbook/035.html). I can live with formatting only, without parsing.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell SDF was not build to be extendable so each Calendar field formatting is hardcoded into one method : (. What I would do is I would create a wrapper object and detect special (handled by me chars) and format output by my own in mixed formats i would divide format into whats before and after my format char, and pass them to original SDF and then glue the results together.

Answer (score 4):

`E` can already be used to get the day of the week. If you want it in hebrew, then [initialize the SimpleDateFormat instance with the hebrew locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

Comment: Can I add custom names that are not part of the Hebrew locale?

Comment: Yes. You could get a copy of the date format symbols for the hebrew locale, overwrite the week days with your own, and then construct the date format using these date format symbols. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html

Comment: That's great. Is there a way to add new symbols, instad of replacing existing ones? There are more than two ways to display a weekday in Hebrew (א', יום א', יום ראשון).

Comment: Then use two different DateFormatSymbols instance: one that would format dates using the first way, and one which would format dates using the second way.

Comment: That menas I can't combine all three ways in the same formatter.

Comment: Indeed. But why would you do that? Isn't one way enough to know what day it is? Wouldn't something like "Monday, the day after Sunday, the day before Tuesday" be redundant?

Comment: I probably don't want all three in the same resulting String. However, I don't want to change the formatter class whenever I edit the Pattern.

Answer (score -1):

## *java.time*

The modern [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) years ago supplanted `SimpleDateFormat`, with the adoption of JSR 310.

Study that class JavaDoc to see its many formatting codes. While largely similar to the codes used in the `SimpleDateFormat` class, there are some differences.

This class can [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) for you. So you may not need to define any formatting pattern.

If you want just the name of the day of the week localized, use [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method.